# POST request using HTTR

Tags: r, api

I am trying to request data using the httr package. [Following this format:](https://api.emsidata.com/apis/core-lmi#basics)

```
args <- list(metrics = c(list(name = "Jobs.2018",as = "Jobs 2018")),
             constraints = list(dimensionName ="Area",
                                map = list("Latah County ID" = c(16057))))

test <- POST(url =
"https://agnitio.emsicloud.com/emsi.us.demographics/2018.3",
     add_headers(`authorization` = paste("bearer",token)),
    add_headers(`content-type` ="application/json"),
    body = toJSON(args,auto_unbox = TRUE),
    verbose())
```

I keep getting a `400 Bad Request` error with everything I have looked up and tried. Do I need to add something to the arguments that I am just not finding?

P.S. I am sorry that this isn't a repeatable example

Comment: If you're getting a 400 that means you're sending something the server doesn't like. Every server is different so there's no way for us to tell what might be wrong. Can you contact support for that service? Without a reproducible example or at least a working request to compare yours to, it's not really going to be possible to help you.

Comment: @MrFlick I am patterning it after the calls on this page: https://api.emsidata.com/apis/core-lmi#basics specifically the first example under "Data Queries"-"Basics"

Comment: @Big_Ozzy it's not the pattern that is the problem it's the server. You can try looking at developer console, copy request as curl, and looking at it to see if there's anything you're missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll assume (a bad thing but necessary for an answer) that you obtained `token` by issuing a prior `POST` request as indicated on the linked API page and then properly decoded the JSON web token into `token`.

*If* you did that properly, then one next likely possibility is malformed `body` data in `POST` request.

When I look at a sample API call:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://agnitio.emsicloud.com/emsi.us.industry/2018.3 \
  --header 'authorization: bearer <access_token>' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{ "metrics": [ { "name": "Jobs.2017", "as":"2017 Jobs" }, { "name": "Establishments.2017" } ], "constraints": [ { "dimensionName": "Area", "map": { "Latah County, ID": ["16057"] } }, { "dimensionName": "Industry", "map": { "Full Service Restaurant s": ["722511"] } } ] }'
```

that sample JSON looks like this pretty-printed:

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "Jobs.2017",
      "as": "2017 Jobs"
    },
    {
      "name": "Establishments.2017"
    }
  ],
  "constraints": [
    {
      "dimensionName": "Area",
      "map": {
        "Latah County, ID": [
          "16057"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "dimensionName": "Industry",
      "map": {
        "Full Service Restaurants": [
          "722511"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Yours looks like:

```
{
  "metrics": {
    "name": "Jobs.2018",
    "as": "Jobs 2018"
  },
  "constraints": {
    "dimensionName": "Area",
    "map": {
      "Latah County ID": 16057
    }
  }
}
```

when it needs to look more like this:

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "Jobs.2018",
      "as": "Jobs 2018"
    }
  ],
  "constraints": [
    {
      "dimensionName": "Area",
      "map": {
        "Latah County ID": [
          "16057"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To do that, we need to use this `list` structure:

```
list(
  metrics = list(
    list(
      name = jsonlite::unbox("Jobs.2018"),
      as = jsonlite::unbox("Jobs 2018")
    )),
  constraints = list(list(
    dimensionName = jsonlite::unbox("Area"),
    map = list("Latah County ID" = c("16057"))
  ))
) -> args
```

Note especially that the API expects that `map` ID JSON data element to be character and not integer/numeric.

Now, we can make the `POST` request like this (spaced out for answer readability as it has embedded comments):

```
httr::POST(

  url = "https://agnitio.emsicloud.com/emsi.us.demographics/2018.3",

  httr::add_headers(
    `authorization` = sprintf("bearer %s", token)
  ),

  encode = "json", # this lets' httr do the work for you

  httr::content_type_json(), # easier than making a header yourself

  body = args,

  httr::verbose()

) -> res
```

That *should* work but b/c it's a closed API without free registration I cannot test it.